# Closed loop stepper with unshielded wires

Tags: stepper-motor, stepper-driver, closed-loop

I've bought a [closed-loop stepper](https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B08724MD2B) from a somewhat reputable manufacturer but was surprised to see 2 things:

[image]

- Power cable is MUCH shorter than the signal cable (they both go to the same place - driver)
- Neither power nor signal cables are shielded

Both seem like absolutely silly for a 100$ product. Wires should be shielded to avoid missing/extra steps and to get correct encoder signals. It also seems pretty hard to fix this post-factum. Am I missing something? Thanks!

Comment: Even if we give you validation, how is that going to solve your problem? Assuming there is a problem as all you’ve done is complain about your poor choice of motor.

Comment: The problem is that I get more erratic behavior on this closed-loop motor than I had on my open-loop that is supposedly more prone to missing steps :) The validation is going to help with decision to a) send this motor back and look for better one or b) accept that this is the state of things and hopefully give some advice on how to prevent EMI issues. Thanks!

Comment: you could post a question about preventing EMI issues ... then you can make a more informed decision